# show div inside another div on hover

Tags: html, css

I have two divs; one inside the other one. I would like to show the inner div when hovered on the outer div, otherwise the inner div should be hidden.  The outer div has an image in it as well (sibling of the inner div) which is always displayed, so when hovered over the image it will also show the text. Can someone help me?

```
<script>
 $(".divone").hover(
    function () {
       $(".divtwo").css("visibility","visible");
    },
    function () {
       $(".divtwo").css("visibility","hidden");
    }
 );
</script>


<div class="divone">
   <div class="divtwo">some text here</div>
   <img src="images/test.png" />
</div>


.divtwo{
    background-color:red;
    top:120px;
    height:50px;
    width:223px;
    position:absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.divone{
     height:169px;
 position:relative;
}
```

Comment: `class"divone"` missing `=`...not sure if typo or carried over from code

Comment: that was a typo. Will fix it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also have a style like this:

```
.divone:hover .divtwo {
   visibility: visible;
}
```

No JS required.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the events to mouseenter and mouseleave events like this.

```
$(".divone").mouseenter(function () {
   $(".divtwo").css("visibility","visible");
});

$(".divone").mouseleave(function () {
   $(".divtwo").css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

Comment: [jQuery `.hover()` is the shorthand for combining `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), so essentially, this part is the same as the OP's original code.  However, [jQuery `.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) is **not** the equivalent of setting CSS `visibility` to `hidden`.  Instead, it sets `display` to `none`... big difference.

Comment: Yes, since `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are the same as `hover`, your code is now identical to the OP's... so how does this help him?